# Cassandra schema to find if a group exists based on an set of users as input

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to define a Cassandra schema for the following use case: Each unique set of users defines a group. The query pattern requires a quick way to find if a group exists based on an set of users as input.

Comment: What makes a set of users unique?  Can you give some examples of what your data would look like and how you intend to query it?

Answer (score 2):

Since there is very little information given, I will make some best-case assumptions here. I am assuming there is a unique way of identifying a user using a fixed length N-bit hash (let's call it uid). I am also assuming that the max number of users (MAX) in a group would be such that (MAX < 64*1024*8 / n). This is because Cassandra has 64KB limit on key length). In real terms this means that if you have up to 32k users, you could form any group up to the max number of users.

Given the above, I would say that a sorted concatenation of the uids would be an easy way to identify the group and the group can be keyed as such.

In that case, a single lookup by the sorted concatenated key formed by the query set of users would give you the answer if you get a hit.

```
Let's say 
key of G1 = u04,u08,u10,u12;
key of G2 = u01,u11,u12;
...
Key of GN = u09,uxx,uyy;
```

If searching whether a group containing users u04, u08, u03, exists, simply create a key "u03,u04,u08" and try and find a hit in the "Groups" column family.

If you are working with a larger user-set with larger users per group, then a different approach may be needed.

**EDIT**: Can you give a sense of maximum how many users may form a group. I assume your client would have to pass a list of all those users as part of he query.